# python websockets set port as None, how can get which port used？

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I used python websockets library create a websocket server, to avoid port has been used by other application, I set port as None, let system choose a port for my websocket server. My problem is how to get which port my websocket server used from program?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Howeverm, I don't found how to use websockets or asyncio to get port. I used netstat -ano to get the port. Here is my code:

```
def get_server_port():
    try:
        current_pid = os.getpid()
        log_utils.get_logger().info(current_pid)
        netstat_cmd = "netstat -ano"
        outs, errs = windows_utils.run_cmd(netstat_cmd, encoding='GBK')
        if errs:
            log_utils.get_logger().error(errs)
        else:
            lines = outs.split('\r\n')
            for line in lines:
                temp = [i for i in line.split(' ') if i != '']
                if len(temp) > 4:
                    if temp[4] == str(current_pid) and temp[3] == 'LISTENING':
                        print(temp)
                        address_array = temp[1].split(':')
                        if len(address_array) > 1:
                            port_str = address_array[1]
                            return int(port_str)
    except BaseException as e:
        log_utils.get_logger().exception(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything about that in documentation, but you can get port from socket

```py
async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", None) as server:
    print(server.sockets[0].getsockname()[1])
```